# Why do I get NSAutoreleasePool double release when using Python/Pyglet on OS X

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard-events, pyglet

I'm using Python 3.5 and Pyglet 1.2.4 on OS X 10.11.5. I am very new to this setup.

I am trying to see if I can use event handling to capture keystrokes (without echoing them to the screen) and return them to the main program one at a time by separate invocations of the pyglet.app.run method. In other words I am trying to use Piglet event handling as if it were a callable function for this purpose.

Below is my test program. It sets up the Pyglet event mechanism and then calls it four times. It works as desired but causes the system messages shown below.

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key

event_loop = pyglet.app.EventLoop()
window = pyglet.window.Window(width=400, height=300,  caption="TestWindow")

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()

@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    global key_pressed
    if symbol == key.A:
        key_pressed = "a"
    else:
        key_pressed = 'unknown'
    pyglet.app.exit()

# Main Program
pyglet.app.run()
print(key_pressed)

pyglet.app.run()
print(key_pressed)

pyglet.app.run()
print(key_pressed)

pyglet.app.run()
print(key_pressed)

print("Quitting NOW!")
```

Here is the output with blank lines inserted for readability. The first message is different and appears even if I comment out the four calls to piglet.app.run. The double release messages do not occur after every call to event handling and do not appear in a consistent manner from one test run to the next.

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 "/Users/home/PycharmProjects/Test Event Handling/.idea/Test Event Handling 03B.py"
>
> 2016-07-28 16:49:59.401 Python[11419:4185158]ApplePersistenceIgnoreState: Existing state will not be touched. New state will be written to /var/folders/8q/bhzsqtz900s742c17gkj_y740000gr/T/org.python.python.savedState
>
> a
>
> 2016-07-28 16:50:02.841 Python[11419:4185158] *** -[NSAutoreleasePool drain]: This pool has already been drained, do not release it (double release).
>
> 2016-07-28 16:50:03.848 Python[11419:4185158] *** -[NSAutoreleasePool drain]: This pool has already been drained, do not release it (double release).
>
> a
>
> a
>
> 2016-07-28 16:50:04.632 Python[11419:4185158] *** -[NSAutoreleasePool drain]: This pool has already been drained, do not release it (double release).
>   a
>   Quitting NOW!
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

**Basic question**: Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

**Alternate question**: Is there a better way to detect and get a users keystrokes without echoing them to the screen. I will be using Python and Pyglet for graphics so I was trying this using Pyglet's event handling.

Comment: You should run ONLY ONE instance of pyglet.app and loop within this single app.  Why would you call pyglet.app 4 times?

Comment: @msarch: I want a function which will wait for a user to press a key then return that key to me without displaying it. (I was hoping to use pyglet.app.run() as such a function.) The screens I want to display will have no text entry fields although they may give that appearance. There will be an apparent text entry field into which they are to enter a well-formed-formula. At any point the set of valid next characters is limited. If they type an invalid character they get a negative response instead of seeing the character. Hence they never see anything incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to play with this simple example. It uses the built-in pyglet event handler to send the key pressed to a function that can then handle it. It shows that pyglet.app itself is the loop. You don't need to create any other.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pyglet


class Win(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Win, self).__init__()

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        # display your output here.... 

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol== pyglet.window.key.ESCAPE:
            exit(0)
        else:
            self.do_something(symbol)
        # etc....

    def do_something(symbol):
        print symbol
        # here you can test the input and then redraw

window = Win()
pyglet.app.run()
```